# Why does print_r not show all properties of WP_User object?

Tags: php, wordpress

If I do this I get many properties shown, including display_name, but the first and last names are NOT shown

```
$user = get_userdata( 4 );
print_r( $user );
```

However they clearly exist because if I immediately afterwards do this, I am shown the proper last name. The Wordpress docs also mention last_name as being a property.

```
echo $user->last_name;
```

So why doesn't print_r show all of the properties? This casts a lot of doubt on being able to use print_r to discover information.

Comment: `last_name` could be provided by a magic getter?

Comment: You can use `RefectionClass::getProperties()` to check or just open the file `<snickers>LoL</snickers>`  http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`last_name` is not a real property of `WP_User`, but it's made available via magic methods for backwards compatibility.

It's listed as a public property [in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#Source_File), but this is a little misleading. More accurately, you can *access it* as a public property. But when you look at [the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php#L0), it's being retrieved and set using magic methods.

## Proof from the Code

Here's an excerpt of the most relevant code, showing how Wordpress actually keeps a list of several of these backward-compatibility properties, including `last_name`, in a private, static property called `back_compat_keys`. When the user requests one of these properties, the magic method `__get` is called. The magic method uses `get_user_meta()` to actually retrieve the data for that property. In other words, the data isn't actually stored in the `WP_User` object; Wordpress just lets you pretend that it is, and it only fetches it when explicitly requested. Here's the code:

```
<?php
class WP_User {
    // ...
        /**
         * @static
         * @since 3.3.0
         * @access private
         * @var array
         */
        private static $back_compat_keys;

        public function __construct( $id = 0, $name = '', $blog_id = '' ) {
                if ( ! isset( self::$back_compat_keys ) ) {
                        $prefix = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix;
                        self::$back_compat_keys = array(
                                'user_firstname' => 'first_name',
                                'user_lastname' => 'last_name',
                                'user_description' => 'description',
                                'user_level' => $prefix . 'user_level',
                                $prefix . 'usersettings' => $prefix . 'user-settings',
                                $prefix . 'usersettingstime' => $prefix . 'user-settings-time',
                        );
                }

                // ...
        }

        // ...

        /**
         * Magic method for accessing custom fields.
         *
         * @since 3.3.0
         * @access public
         *
         * @param string $key User meta key to retrieve.
         * @return mixed Value of the given user meta key (if set). If `$key` is 'id', the user ID.
         */
        public function __get( $key ) {
                // ...

                if ( isset( $this->data->$key ) ) {
                        $value = $this->data->$key;
                } else {
                        if ( isset( self::$back_compat_keys[ $key ] ) )
                                $key = self::$back_compat_keys[ $key ];
                        $value = get_user_meta( $this->ID, $key, true );
                }

                // ...

                return $value;
        }

        /**
         * Magic method for setting custom user fields.
         *
         * This method does not update custom fields in the database. It only stores
         * the value on the WP_User instance.
         *
         * @since 3.3.0
         * @access public
         *
         * @param string $key   User meta key.
         * @param mixed  $value User meta value.
         */
        public function __set( $key, $value ) {
                if ( 'id' == $key ) {
                        _deprecated_argument( 'WP_User->id', '2.1.0',
                                sprintf(
                                        /* translators: %s: WP_User->ID */
                                        __( 'Use %s instead.' ),
                                        '<code>WP_User->ID</code>'
                                )
                        );
                        $this->ID = $value;
                        return;
                }

                $this->data->$key = $value;
        }

        /**
         * Magic method for unsetting a certain custom field.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         * @access public
         *
         * @param string $key User meta key to unset.
         */
        public function __unset( $key ) {
                // ...

                if ( isset( $this->data->$key ) ) {
                        unset( $this->data->$key );
                }

                if ( isset( self::$back_compat_keys[ $key ] ) ) {
                        unset( self::$back_compat_keys[ $key ] );
                }
        }

        // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code makes more sense now. Some new OOP concepts for me to learn.